# SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I've written the following:

```
double waitTime = 10;

new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(waitTime).until
(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']"))).sendKeys("John Doe"));
```

The error I'm getting for the above code is 'TimeSpan' does not contain a definition for 'until'..
I was under the impression that 'until' was a part of the 'SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers' library ?

Comment: You are missing closing `)` for `WebDriverWait` before `until`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using c#, I think you just need a couple typographical fixes.  As @Guy mentioned, you are missing a closing parenthesis before until; Also the methods `Until` and `SendKeys` need to start with a capital letter in C#.  So I think it should be

```
double waitTime = 10;

new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(waitTime)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']"))).SendKeys("John Doe"));
```

or I think it's a little more clear if you split your wait into two lines:

```
double waitTime = 10;

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(waitTime));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']"))).SendKeys("John Doe"));
```

My one outstanding question is about your wait time--10 milliseconds? That will make it so that it will wait AT MOST 10 ms, is this what you want?

Comment: Sweet, thanks C.Peck ! It is indeed better to arrange the code in the way you suggested.